# How to show 'No Start Date' in fields without date Using DATEDIFF with GETDATE to Calculate years

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions! I am trying to show number of years student has been in school.  However, if there is no entrydate the output shows 120 years.  Is there a way to show  'No Entry Date' or '-' in the YearsInSchools field?  This is what I've tried...

```
select   Last_Name,[SchoolEntryDate], 
    case when  [SchoolEntryDate] is null then 'No Entry Date' else DATEDIFF(year, [SchoolEntryDate],  GETDATE()) 
    end as YearsInSchool

,case when s.[SchoolEntryDate] is null then '-' 
         when s.[SchoolEntryDate]  is not null then DATEDIFF(year, [SchoolEntryDate], GETDATE()) 
          end AS "Years_in_Schools"

    from  Students  
    where  Status ='0'
```

this is the output:

```
LastName        SchoolEntryDate   YearsInSchools
Alexander       2016-08-08           4
Ragland                              120
Marlow                               120
Boyd            2019-08-21           1
Armstrong       2015-08-03           5
Ryder                                120
Gayden                               120
```

This is the desired output I'm trying to achieve

```
LastName        SchoolEntryDate   YearsInSchools
Alexander       2016-08-08           4
Ragland                              'No Entry Date'
Marlow                               'No Entry Date'
Boyd            2019-08-21           1
Armstrong       2015-08-03           5
Ryder                                'No Entry Date'
Gayden                               'No Entry Date'
```

Comment: You have tagged MySQL and yet the query will not run in MySQL.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: (1) This has to be SQL Server (2) If this query encouters a `null` value in `SchoolEntryDate`, then the query would raise a conversion error. You would need to provide an actual reproducible example.